# SwiftUI IOS 14 New AppDeligate with .environmentObject

Tags: swiftui

For the new delegate file in iOS 14 I need to include both the .environmentObject settings and the UserSettings: ObservableObject  (which is a Realm Class).

But I first need to create the User data if there is none (first time user) otherwise it give me a null error and crashes.

Where would I put the code to initiate the user before calling it in the body loads?

```
@main
struct myapp_App: App {

   let userSettings = UserSettings()  // calling the data which will not exist if initial user

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(userSettings)
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think it should be not at this level. You should at first fetch users from Realm (say on appear of root view showing loading/connecting etc)... and if there is no user, then show some UI creating new user, etc, etc.

Comment: think I just figured it out.  which this I was able to set up things like in the old AppDelegate.   @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

Comment: class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
      
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {  }

Answer (score 0):

I put the code to create the user if first time inside the int() of the ObservableObject.

I hope can only hope this code is proper?  But it works.

Good luck.

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
 
    @Published var name: String? = nil
    @Published var email: String? = nil

    init(){
      
        if User.userExist() == false {
            User.initiateUser()
        }
    
        let u = User.getUser()
    
        name = u!.name
        email = u!.email

    }
 
}
```